# How to catch URL the user clicks in php and redirect to a particular html file in the same page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a main page portfolio where i have thumbnails that showcase my works. I want to redirect to specific page in the pop-up whenever a user clicks that specified thumbnail.

In order to that i want to redirect it through a php file where i will catch the url the user is clicking and redirect to the specified site.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: read the rules before posting. srsly.

Comment: You should have goggled, anyway try `header` in php

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in php

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');/* Redirect browser */
```

Comment: can i put local link to site like header('Location: www/bb/3.html')  ?

Comment: You can put local link, @Tridip. One thing to be careful of, though, with headers is to make sure you are not outputting any html before the header() function in the file (ie echo 'something';). Not even a blank line.